# 'list' object has no attribute 'isEmpty' when I want to check if Dataframe is empty

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I create a dataframe d2 and want to apply a function to see if it is empty or not. I get the error:  **'list' object has no attribute 'isEmpty'**

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import DecimalType, FloatType, StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType 
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, DoubleType, BooleanType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,array_contains, monotonically_increasing_id, when
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as W
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField 
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, IntegerType, ArrayType
from pyspark.sql.functions import round, lit


sc = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkByExamples.com').getOrCreate()

columns2 = ["Java","Python"]
data2 = [("Java", "20000"), ("Hello", "100000"), ("Scala", "3000")]
df2 = sc.createDataFrame(data2).toDF(*columns2)

print(df2.head(1).isEmpty)
```

In the last line I get an error. Can someone help me?

Comment: In your own words, what do you expect `df2.head(1)` to mean? What do you think it will do when `df2` is empty? What do you think it will do when `df2` is not empty? Now, take a step back, and think. `df2` is the thing where you want to check whether it's empty or not, right? Does *that* thing provide `isEmpty`? What does that do? Does it solve your problem directly? So, what code should you write?

Comment: Can you post the traceback?

Comment: This is tagged pandas but pandas doesn't seem to be involved.

Comment: Or maybe it is. Not sure what `sc.createDataFrame(data2).toDF(*columns2)` does. Can you `print(type(df2))` so we can see what it is?

Answer (score 4):

`IsEmpty` is a method belonging to a pyspark DataFrame.
`.head()` is returning a list of `Row` objects as written in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.head.html).
A list object in python indeed has not method called `IsEmpty`

Comment: How could I check if Dataframe is empty or not?

Comment: Just call to `isEmpty` directly on `df2` witjout the head

Comment: You could try check if the condition `df2.count() == 0` is `True`.
If this answers your question please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Depends what you mean by empty, `len(df) == 0` ?

Comment: I get the following error: "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'isEmpty'"

Comment: @Bice isEmpty is a method not an attribute, run `df2.isEmpty()` (add parenthesis)

Answer (score 1):

In the last line you are calling to [DataFrame.head()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.head.html) which returns a **list** and not a DataFrame as written in the documentation.

> Returns:
> If n is greater than 1, return a list of Row.
> If n is 1, return a single Row.

So, as a result, the `isEmpty()` method is called on the returned list

Answer (score 0):

df.head(1).isEmpty won't work for PySpark. Use something like this:

```
if len(release_df.head(1)) == 0:
       <do something>
```